# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

```
INFO\[0;39m \[35m13756\[0;39m \[2m---\[0;39m \[2m\[           main\]\[0;39m \[36mo.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils     \[0;39m \[2m:\[0;39m Failed to introspect annotations on \[class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration\]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain annotation attribute value for public abstract java.lang.Class\[\] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass.value()
\[2m2023-10-11 11:02:42.725\[0;39m \[32m INFO\[0;39m \[35m13756\[0;39m \[2m---\[0;39m \[2m\[           main\]\[0;39m \[36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext\[0;39m \[2m:\[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5c530d1e: startup date \[Wed Oct 11 11:02:42 IST 2023\]; root of context hierarchy
\[2m2023-10-11 11:02:42.898\[0;39m \[31mERROR\[0;39m \[35m13756\[0;39m \[2m---\[0;39m \[2m\[           main\]\[0;39m \[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              \[0;39m \[2m:\[0;39m Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:283) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:127) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:187) \~\[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102) \~\[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68) \~\[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) \~\[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE\]
at com.recruitment.app.RecruitmentRegistryApplication.main(RecruitmentRegistryApplication.java:11) \~\[classes/:na\]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:122) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393) \~\[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException--\>Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte\[\],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6a8658ff
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.\<clinit\>(Enhancer.java:73) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte\[\],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6a8658ff
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.\<clinit\>(ReflectUtils.java:52) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) \~\[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE\]
... 38 common frames omitted
```

application.properties

```
server.port = 8761
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class RecruitmentRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RecruitmentRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

i just want to start this service discovery application to be up .what are things need other than this kindlt help

I tried to run the service discovery microservice in my local with netflix eureka. but im getting above error.